# Realm - Can't set object of type subclass to property of type parent class

Tags: realm

Hi everyone,

I encounter a little problem with Realm, I have a class "Contact" and a subclass "Person" defined as :

Person.h

```
#import <Realm/Realm.h>
#import "Contact.h"

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Person)

@interface Person : Contact

@property NSString * nickName;

@end
```

I have an other entity called "Address" which has a "Contact" property ( an address can only be related to one contact ).

Address.h

```
#import <Realm/Realm.h>
@class Contact;

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Address)

@interface Address : RLMObject

@property NSString * city;
@property NSString * country;

@property RLMContact *contact;

@end
```

The problem is : when I try to set a "Person" object to the contact property of "Address", I got this error :

```
[address setContact:person];
'Can't set object of type 'Person' to property of type 'Contact'
```

I tried to cast it but still the same issue :

```
[address setContact:(Contact *)person];
'Can't set object of type 'Person' to property of type 'Contact'
```

I even tried after defining the Person class on my Address.h but still the same problem :

Address.h

```
#import <Realm/Realm.h>
@class Contact;
@class Person;

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Address)

@interface Address : RLMObject

@property NSString * city;
@property NSString * country;

@property RLMContact *contact;

@end
```

Anyone has an idea ?

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Realm, while you can subclass your `RLMObject` entities, those subclasses aren't polymorphic. That is to say, you cannot substitute a `Person` object when you say you're linking to a `Contact` object, because Realm treats them as entirely separate entities.

Comment: I'd say this is a pretty big failing point, sitting on top of an object oriented language, especially with a more complicated database. Could this be considered to be a feature?

Comment: We intend to introduce some sort of polymorphism down the road, but it requires major changes to the underlying database engine. You can follow https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1109 for updates on that.